# Problems while doing $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\mu)}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, classical-field-theory

In [David Tong's lectures](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf), he gives two Lagrangians as examples to derive the equations of motion:

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\,\partial_\mu\phi\,\partial_\nu \phi-\dfrac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2, \tag{1}$$
$$\mathcal{L} = -\dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu)+\dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2. \tag{2}$$

I want to do the calculations explicitly, but I have a problem with a particular derivative. For (1) I have:

$$\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial(\partial_\sigma \phi)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left( \eta^{\mu\nu} \dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}{\partial(\partial_\sigma \phi)} \partial_\nu \phi + \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \dfrac{\partial (\partial_\nu \phi) }{\partial(\partial_\sigma \phi)} \right),$$

and for (2) I have:

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)} =-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)} (\partial^\mu A^\nu) -\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial(\partial^\mu A^\nu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)} (\partial_\mu A_\nu)+ \partial_\mu A^\mu \dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu A^\mu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}.$$

As you can see, I don't know how to simplify $\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}{\partial(\partial_\sigma \phi)}$ or $\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$. He only shows the result of $\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}$ and of $\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$ for each Lagrangian. What do I do? What are the steps to simplify such expressions?

Comment: Tip: What would $\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial X^\nu}$ and $\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial X^\mu}$ be for an arbitrary vector $X$? There's no difference to the terms that you try to deal with that would matter.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think $\dfrac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial X^\mu} =1$ and $\dfrac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial X^\nu}=0$ if $\mu \neq \nu$; 1 if $\mu = \nu$.

Comment: Absolutely correct, though it is more conventional to simply write the latter statement with a [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta^\mu_\nu$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind According to that, $\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}{\partial(\partial_\sigma \phi)}=\delta^{\mu}_{\sigma}$ and $\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}=1$ and $\dfrac{\partial(\partial^\mu A^\nu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}=1$ and $\dfrac{\partial(\partial_\mu A^\mu)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}=\delta^\mu_\nu$. Although I don't know if the third expression is right.

Comment: As an aside, you ought to watch your indices: When taking a derivative, take the derivative w.r.t different indices to make sure einstein summation convention is preserved (i.e. no more than 2 of any particular index).